# Suggestions for alternative to Azure cloud load testing

Tags: azure, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Can anyone please suggest an alternative to cloud-based load testing (free/open-source). Since the load testing feature would be deprecated on azure in a few months, what are people in the market opting for besides AWS.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @asneemS Have you tried out Gatling.io, How did it go?

Comment: Hi Levi , I havent tried out Gatling since I am looking for something to work with JMeter for the moment. Are you looking for something similar?

Comment: @TasneemS, You could also get thedetailed information about the Azure cloud load testing here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/cloud-based-load-testing-service-eol/, it also shared the Load testing Alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [Gatling.io](https://gatling.io/) to load test our enterprise application that is hosted in Azure App Service. It both offers free open source and enterprise tiers, easily configurable and produces a pretty fancy output that managers will love.

You can configure scenarios in Scala scripts, of which I was afraid first, but it's pretty easy and self explanatory documentation made it easy to configure even with zero previous knowledge of the Scala language.

*Disclaimer: I'm in no way affiliated with the developers of gatling.io, simply their product is great.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a cloud-based solution to run your JMeter tests you should see the cloud provider which supports JMeter.

As of now the options are in:

1. Self-hosted JMeter in cloud where everything is up to you (you can use scripts developed by enthusiasts like [jmeter-ec2](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) or [jmeter-aws](https://github.com/jneyer/jmeter-aws))
2. [Flood.io](https://flood.io/load-performance-testing-tool/)
3. [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com/blog/)
4. [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) (the latter one is [recommended by Microsoft](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/microsoft-recommends-jmeter-and-blazemeter-as-preferred-load-testing-tools/))